# Attach Behavior to all Models

Tags: php, yii

I'm using `Yii Framework` and would like to attach a behavior named `datetimeI18NBehavior` to all models.

I'm doing it manually adding the following code to each Model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'datetimeI18NBehavior' => array('class' => 'ext.DateTimeI18NBehavior')
    );
}
```

It's possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a base model class with this function, and have your other classes extend your base model.